# Running Monkeyrunner from pydev

Tags: jython, pydev, monkeyrunner

Hi I want to run python scripts developed from Monkeyrunner in Eclips-Pydev setup.
I have installed Jython and mapped the Jython interpreter and added the Monkeyrunner.jar to Pydev also.
But still I'm not able to import com.android.monkeyrunner package in Pydev.
Any Help??
Regards,
ram

Answer (score 1):

At First You have to set the path of monkeyrunner which is :

```
export PATH=/home/<Directory name where android-sdk is located>/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools:$PATH
```

After that open your terminal and run the command monkeyrunner

Comment: This works for the command line, but yes, I still can't get eclipse to import the monkeyrunner package...